# Hash function to hash ip fragments

Tags: c, algorithm, function, hash

I have to hash incoming ipv4 fragments to a static array of structures of size 20. The fields to be used for hashing are IP-ID(16 bit), Protocol(8 bit) , Source IP Address(32 bit) and Destination IP Address(32 bit). The hash should be fast and not very complex to implement in C. What would be a good hash function in this case?

Comment: That sounds very small considering the total key space, you're going to smash 88 bits of key space into less than 5 bits of "index space". This sounds as if it will make collisions very likely. If the items are going to stick around and/or come quickly, the hash table will probably be very full (or have very long external chains).

Comment: Record some real live data and analyze different hash functions if the distribute them evenly on your 20 array entries. However you will have plenty of collisions because of the very small array.

Comment: Are you talking about a array of 20 bytes or bits? If it's 20 bytes you don't have to hash but you could just `memcpy` them.

Comment: by 20 i mean no of entries is 20

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your correctly and you want only 20 possible hashes, you could use modulo operator (`%`) directly on your data.

If your data distribution is favourable and you are storing them as integers you might get away with `hash = ip_fragment % 20`.

It seems like a lot of collisions is going to happen anyway, so you may keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume all the parameters are uncorrelated and distributed evenly, then you can just xor all the bytes of the fields you are interested in together, and finally take the result modulo 20. However, if you have bidirectional flows that means both directions are hashed to the same value (since swapping fields does not matter in this simple algorithm).
You should probably look at fast generic hash algorithms like MurmurHash.

However, with only 20 entries in your hash table, you are very likely to get collisions. If there is a strong correlation in time between received packets, for example you are very likely to receive many packets with identical headers in a row, then instead you might be better off just having a single (or a few) cache entries that only record the last (unique) received header(s), and then you immediately compare the next packet with those cache entries without doing any hash.

Don't forget to measure the actual perfomance of the hash or cache method you are using.

Answer (score 0):

% 20 is really sub-optimal. A simple hash like this:

```
uint_32_t ip_fragment_hash(uint16_t ip_id, uint8_t ip_proto, uint32_t ip_src, uint32_t ip_dst)
{
  return (ip_id << 16 | ip_proto) ^ ip_src ^ ip_dst;
}
```

is 5 amd64 instructions (shift, mov, xor, xor, or, xor). But add the `% 20` and you get to 14 instructions, including one expansive multiplication. Make it 32 and just fold it:

```
uint32_t ip_fragment_hash(uint16_t ip_id, uint8_t ip_proto, uint32_t ip_src, uint32_t ip_dst)
{
  uint32_t h = (ip_id << 16 | ip_proto) ^ ip_src ^ ip_dst;
  h = h ^ (h >> 5) ^ (h >> 10) ^ (h >> 15)  ^ (h >> 20) ^ (h >> 25) ^ (h >> 30);
  return h % 32;
}
```

Comment: Your folding adds 12 instructions. But indeed it is a good technique. However, using `ip_src ^ ip_dst` might not be a good idea, it maps both directions of a bidirectional flow to the same hash entry.